# Laravel composer dump-autoload not applying new PSR-4 structure

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, psr-4

My PSR4 structure isn't registering when I `composer dump-autoload`. This my composer, the entry is src/Booksmart :

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/controllers/Api",
    ]
},
"psr-4": {
    "Booksmart\\": "src/Booksmart"
},
```

and this is my directory structure:

```
src/
    Booksmart/
        Advance/
            Advance.php
```

The Advance.php looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Booksmart\Advance

class Advance
{

}
```

My `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` doesn't show the new entry for my Booksmart namespace though, and is definitely not loading the Advance.php class. This seems so simple to screw up, what am I missing?

Comment: psr-4 should be inside autoload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PSR-4 must be inside autoload:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/controllers/Api",
    ],

    "psr-4": {
        "Booksmart\\": "src/Booksmart"
    },

},
```

Comment: Well, I've done the same. But, when I use dump-autoload " without -o" it doesn't include my PSR-4. but the optimized does. Can you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I thing you don't need compose. In my case I am paying namespace like this in "Advance" class.For Example `namespace App\src\Bookmart\Advance`. And then in the dependency class `use App\src\Bookmart\Advance;`.